# Rails method running set timeout - determine how long thread "stays" in a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, methods, timeout

I have a tasks that do a lot of things, some of these can "blocks" because it call an external API.

My question: is possible to determine how long the RailsThread "stays" in a method? and so on  interrupts it or reload if take too long. The problem is that there is no error, so I can't do anything like rescue.

A pseudo code that I want to do:

```
def aMethod
  #doSomethingThatCanBlock
  if takeMoreThan1000ms
    #reloadMethod or break
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
require 'timeout'

def a_method(iterations)
  Timeout::timeout(1) do # 1 second
    iterations.times { |i| print("#{i} "); sleep(0.1) }
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  print("TIMEOUT")
ensure
  puts
end
```

And an example:

```
irb(main):012:0> a_method(3)
0 1 2 
=> 3
irb(main):013:0> a_method(30)
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 TIMEOUT
=> nil
```

Comment: are you missing a begin?

Comment: Not really, the syntax is valid.